# Python - Blender Game Engine: _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__."a class"'>: attribute lookup "a class" on __main__ failed

Tags: python, pickle, blender

```
import pickle

class NoClass():
    def __init__(self, name, level, cls, time_played):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level
        self.cls = cls
        self.time_played = time_played

def Write_char_file(registered_username):
    avatar = NoClass('',1,'',0) #--------i am trying to pickle and write this
    a = str('Characters\%s.txt' % registered_username) #---- the saving file
    f = open(a, 'wb')
    f.write(pickle.dumps(avatar))
    f.close()

def Asign_to_slot(char_lst):
    pass

Asign_to_slot(Write_char_file('my_name'))
```

> When trying to run this in bge it raises that error
>       BUT when i run it with python IDLE there isn't a problem
>       and i manage to write the pickled class in the file
>       though i know classes usually can't be pickled
>       then i even manage to open the file, unpickle it and print
>       the class' attributes

```
"_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.NoClass'>: attribute lookup NoClass on __main__ failed"
```

Comment: Dunno much about `bge`, but I can verify that this code works with Cpython (Python2 and Python3) out of the box. Also not sure why you got a downvote. Seems like a good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this works when run in blender and only fails in the game engine, I would assume that this relates to an optimisation made in the game engines python binding.

Following the [handling stateful objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#handling-stateful-objects) example and adding a custom `__getstate__` also fails, indicating that the game engine probably implements custom [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to only provide a minimal feature set.

The solution would appear to be pickling the objects `__dict__` directly, you would then also unpickle to the new instances `__dict__`.

```
f.write(pickle.dumps(avatar.__dict__))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working well as long as I treat it like a dictionary when unpickled. One last question -  is it possible to reverse this process (dict to class)? If not how do I access the class methods after unpickling? Thank you once again!

Comment: Going by the handle stateful example, `newavatar = NoClass() newavatar.__dict__.update(unpickled_dict)`